# What is the difference between secret hats and normal hats?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

I have seen that many hats have a certain criteria to be earned, but secret hats don't have any criteria! Is this magic? What is the difference between secret hats and normal hats?

Comment: why all those down vote?

Comment: I suppose 'lack of research'. For a Stack Overflow veteran, it's quite obvious.

Comment: i know about them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the available *normal* hats, and the criteria to obtain them, are made public as soon as Winter Bash starts, this isn't the case for *secret* hats.

Which secret hats exist, and the criteria for them, are revealed in the 'wrap up' at the end of Winter Bash. The community is [reasonably successful](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288284/295232) in discovering them beforehand, with or without the help of [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats#comment936707_288284) [hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats#comment936958_288284) from the Stack Overflow developers.